# Append to Union query

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible, using VBA to add another query to a Union query? 
for example, the sql of a union query:

```
select Max(qryTRInputPriorityList_SS.DT1) AS MaxOfDT1
From qryTRinputPriorityList_SS
UNION ALL select Max(qryTRInputPriorityList_MB.DT1) AS MaxOfDT1
From qryTRinputPriorityList_MB;
```

and using VBA I want to add another select query to the sql above:

```
select Max(qryTRInputPriorityList_SS.DT1) AS MaxOfDT1
From qryTRinputPriorityList_SS
UNION ALL select Max(qryTRInputPriorityList_MB.DT1) AS MaxOfDT1
From qryTRinputPriorityList_MB
UNION ALL select Max(qryTRInputPriorityList_GS.DT1) AS MaxOfDT1
From qryTRinputPriorityList_GS;
```

any code samples or anything would help,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
Dim Sql As String

Sql = Replace(CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query1").SQL, ";", vbCrLf)
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query1").SQL = Sql & CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query2").SQL
```

Query1 now holds the combined SQL of the two queries.

For repeated usage, store the original SQL of Query1 somewhere.

Comment: Fantastic, put me on the right line of thinking and now solved :)